# Apagar rows de uma tabela exceto uma quantia MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, tabela-html

Tenho em uma tabela as colunas:

`codigo, cliente, token_md, val, cartcodigo, clientenome, clientesobrenome, clientecpf, clientenascimento`

Preciso apagar exatamente 46.550 linhas dessa tabela, sem preocupações de ordem.

Comment: Faz um `delete ... where codigo in (select ... limit 46550)`, mas é bem esquisito você precisar de algo assim...

Answer (score 0):

Fazer o delete utilizando o `LIMIT` não conseguimos limitar o número de linhas, uma forma de fazer isso, é criando uma tabela temporária limitando o número de linhas, e depois removemos a tabela original e recriamos com base na temporária. Assim:

**1.Criação da tabela temporária:**

```
CREATE TABLE tabela_temporaria
  SELECT codigo
        ,cliente
        ,token_md
        ,val
        ,cartcodigo
        ,clientenome
        ,clientesobrenome
        ,clientecpf
        ,clientenascimento
    FROM tabela
   LIMIT > 46550
```

**2.Então removemos a tabela original:**

```
DROP TABLE tabela;
```

**3.Recriar tabela original baseado na temporaria**

```
CREATE TABLE tabela
  SELECT codigo
        ,cliente
        ,token_md
        ,val
        ,cartcodigo
        ,clientenome
        ,clientesobrenome
        ,clientecpf
        ,clientenascimento
    FROM tabela_temporaria
```

Comment: Mas aí não está deixando justamente os itens que ele quer remover? Não seria LIMIT > 46550?

Comment: Oo.. obrigado @adventistaam não vou me justificar. Errei e assumo :)